# Unable to select dropdown on website in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, automation, html-select

I am trying to automate a web navigation. I am stuck at selecting the dropdown. This is what I have so far:

```
the_Start:
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim objIE As Object
    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    objIE.Top = 0
    objIE.Left = 0
    objIE.Width = 800
    objIE.Height = 600
    objIE.Visible = True
    objIE.navigate ("https://suit.cibil.com")

    With objIE
        Do While .Busy
            DoEvents
        Loop
        Do While .ReadyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
    End With
    
    While objIE.Busy
        DoEvents
    Wend
    
    If objIE.Busy = False Then
    
        Set the_input_elements = objIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("select")
        
        For Each input_element In the_input_elements
        
            If input_element.getAttribute("name") = "croreAccount" Then
                'MsgBox ("Found croreAccount")
                Set option1 = input_element.getElementsByTagName("option")
                For Each dropdown1 In option1
                    If dropdown1.Value = "1" Then
                        'MsgBox dropdown1.Text
                        dropdown1.Focus
                        dropdown1.FireEvent ("onchange")
                        dropdown1.Click
                        dropdown1.Selected = "selected"
                        dropdown1.Selected = True
                    End If
                Next
            End If
            
        Next
        
    End If
End Sub
```

'This opens the website, and correctly takes me to option tab, but do not select them. Please help as' 'this is extremely repetetive work'

---

HTML

```html
<select name="croreAccount" class="select" id="croreAccount" style="z-index: 10; opacity: 0;" onchange="changeQuarter(this);">
    <option selected="selected" value="0">Option</option>
    <option value="1">Search</option>
    <option value="2">Summary - Credit Institutions Wise List</option>
    <option value="3">Summary - State/Union Territory</option>
</select>
```

Comment: html code is<select name="croreAccount" class="select" id="croreAccount" style="z-index: 10; opacity: 0;" onchange="changeQuarter(this);">
    <option selected="selected" value="0">Option</option>
    <option value="1">Search</option>
    <option value="2">Summary - Credit Institutions Wise List</option>
    <option value="3">Summary - State/Union Territory</option>


</select>

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you can use the id to target the appropriate `select` element. You don't need any looping as you can then select the required option using its `value` attribute. After making your selected by setting the option as `selected = True`, you need to attach a change `HTMLEvent` to the parent `select` element and dispatch it so the node registers the options change and updates

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()

    Dim objIE As Object
    
    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    
    objIE.Visible = True
    objIE.navigate "https://suit.cibil.com"
    
    Dim evt As Object
    
    With objIE
    
        While .busy Or .ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
        
        .document.querySelector("#croreAccount [value='1']").Selected = True
        
        Set evt = .document.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
        evt.initEvent "change", True, False
        
        .document.querySelector("#croreAccount").dispatchEvent evt
        
        Stop

        .Quit

    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Sir, it is showing object required. Is there any reference library addition required

Comment: which line please?

Comment: It may be that you need a longer wait for page load after `While .busy Or .ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend`